# Как сравнить время Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, дата, datetime

```
def _is_work_time(self, start, end):
    now_str = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
    return start <= now_str <= end
```

Функция принимает 2 аргумента в формате H:M.

Например: передаем `start=8:30, end=4:30`.
Задача такая, нужно реализовать чтобы функция возвращала `true`, если время сейчас от 8:30 до 4:30(след дня), или до 23:30(при `end=23:30`)(того же дня, что и `start`), а в остальных случаях `false`.

Comment: Откуда функция узнает, что `4:30` это именно следующего дня? Или предполагаем, что `end > start` всегда ? И если будет `8:31`, то это еще этого дня или тоже следующего?

Comment: @RomanKonoval, дополнил вопрос

Comment: Несколько уточнил свой вариант ответа. Как писал @RomanKonoval, что функция не знает какой сейчас день (завтра или все-таки сегодня) и 4:30 какого дня (рабочего или нет). С учетом этого функция сводится к проверке либо попадания в интервал времени, либо наоборот. Поправил свой вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Уточнил функцию. Если не знать начальную дату, то мы имеем задачу о попадании в интервал времени `start < end`, либо непопадании в него, когда `start >= end`.

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta


def is_work_time(start_time: str, end_time: str):
    now = datetime.now().time()
    start = time.fromisoformat(start_time)
    end = time.fromisoformat(end_time)
    return any([now <= end, now >= start]) if not start < end else (start <= now <= end)


print(is_work_time('08:30', '23:30'))
print(is_work_time('08:30', '04:30'))
```

Вариант с известной датой выхода на работу:

```
def is_work_datetime(start_date: str, start_time: str, end_time: str):
    now = datetime.now()
    date_ = date.fromisoformat(start_date)
    start = time.fromisoformat(start_time)
    end = time.fromisoformat(end_time)
    if start < end:
        start = datetime.combine(date_, time.fromisoformat(start_time))
        end = datetime.combine(date_, time.fromisoformat(end_time))
    else:
        start = datetime.combine(date_, time.fromisoformat(start_time))
        end = datetime.combine(date_ + timedelta(days=1), time.fromisoformat(end_time))
    return start <= now <= end


print(is_work_datetime('2021-07-01', '08:30', '23:30'))
print(is_work_datetime('2021-06-30', '08:30', '04:30'))
```